# C# barcode printing stalled because of fontstyle

Tags: c#, printing, fonts, barcode

I have an application where I can take text and convert it to a barcode using a 3 of 9 font, and print it.  While it will print when the font style is bold or italic, it seems to stall at the print() when using no font style.  Visual Studio gives me an Access Violation Exception.  I find it strange that a font style is seems to be the cause of this.  Any suggestions would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: You may not realize this, but a font is really just a type of .dll file that is saved with a .fon or .ttf file extension.  It can throw errors just like any .dll.  Especially if you are running it with settings that the programmer didn't implement or support.

Comment: I think using fonts for creating barcodes is a bad idea. We use free library which allows to create image.

Comment: It was really fun in the days before NT when a font could cause Windows to crash or your computer to reboot.

Comment: For the code, the only line that I would need to be checked is  Font barcode = new System.Drawing.Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 8, FontStyle.Regular);  FontStyle is the only thing I have to change, otherwise no problems occur.  I was told to use a font for this, so that was my only option.  But thanks.  I'll try looking more into the library.